# Best Free Online Source Control

Tags: version-control

There are many free online Source Control available but I would like to know your experience on it, if any, and which is the best one?

Me and my friend are starting a small test project and would like some really good online source control.

We will be developing ASP.Net app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're just after a hosted source code repository:

- [Github](http://github.com/)
- [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/)

If you need issue tracking, file releases, wikis, mailing lists, etc:

- [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/)
- [Google Code Hosting](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/GettingStarted)

I've got one project at Sourceforge, and I find the amenities quite nice.  You might find [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities) handy.

Comment: Not sure how well they compare to the others, but github does provide issue tracking, wikis, and automatic (source) releases of tagged revisions.  The wikis are, as of fairly recently, git-backed, which is neat.

Comment: Bitbucket provides issue tracking, wikis (Mercurial or Git backed) and automatic released of tagged revisions as well. Plus, Bitbucket offers private repositories for free (Github too, but not for free), whereas Google Code, for example, is **only** for open source (I don't know about Sourceforge).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) for some personal stuff to avoid issues with corporate firewalls.

You can commit over http with them.

Otherwise, use Github as already suggested.

Comment: Hi Eddy, what about if I want one of my friend to use it as well. Even the limit is only 200mb. Size is fine but I want multiple users (probably couple of us).

Comment: @Nimesh: see http://unfuddle.com/about/tour/plans A couple is 2. ;)

Comment: that is free for 14 days.. only